# Excel formula, nested IFs

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to adjust a pre existing IF formula and not getting much luck. 
It should quote:

`N/A` if a cell is populated with NA,

`Out of Date` if the date in cell is 12 months or more old

`Due` if its 11 months old,

`In date` if it is within 12 months

This is the pre existing formula, I know its wrong but I don't know where its going wrong.

```
= IF(N15>(NOW()-395)+60,"In Date", IF(N15>(NOW()-395), "Due",IF(N15=NA,"N/A", "OUT OF DATE"))
```

Please help

Comment: Is NA not a string? Should it be `IF(N15="NA",`

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be `In date` if it is within 1**1** months. Not **12**

Answer (score 2):

You need to test the *furthest away* **first** because it will match the other rules as well, so eliminate it first.

```
 =IF(A1="NA","N/A",IF(A1<TODAY()-365,"Out of Date",IF(A1<TODAY()-335,"Due",IF(A1>=TODAY()-335,"In Date"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you would use:

```
=IF(N15="NA", "N/A", IF(ISNUMBER(DATEVALUE(N15)),IF(N15<EDATE(NOW(),-12),"OUT OF DATE",IF(N15<EDATE(NOW(),-11),"Due","In Date")), "Not a valid date"))
```

Here are some tips:

1. Use `EDATE` to calculate 12 months old and 11 months old instead of using `NOW-395`.
2. When checking for `NA`, include that in double quotes in the formula.
3. Add logic to check if the value entered is not a date (text, number blank cell etc.) since it would otherwise lead to unexpected results.
4. You may also want to check if the date is a future date and display a different result if that is the case.
5. The order of checking these conditions matter in most cases. If you have a formula to check the same conditions in a different order will give different results.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the "NA" test first, since it's like a Zero when testing (you will get `Due` instead).
I'm not sure if you switched the `due` and `In date`. I changed it to comply to your rule `due` if it's 11 months old.

```
= IF(N15="NA","N/A",IF(N15>(NOW()-395)+60,"Due", IF(N15>(NOW()-395), "In date","OUT OF DATE")))
```